# Python3 How can I convert list to dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list like:
`lst=[['a',1],['b',2],['a',3],['b',1],['a',1]]`

How can I convert this to dictionary like that:
`dct={'a':[1,3,1],'b':[2,1]}`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The default dictionary can help you

```
from collections import defaultdict

ddict = defaultdict(list)

data = [['a',1],['b',2],['a',3],['b',1],['a',1]]
for key, value in data:
    ddict[key].append(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lst = [['a',1],['b',2],['a',3],['b',1],['a',1]]
dct = {}
for [k, v] in lst:
    dct[k] = dct[k] + [v] if k in dct else [v]
```